# Python bs4 how to find inline style from find_all()

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to get the height value of an inline style element using python and BeautifulSoup i manage to get all div with a specific class but cannot figure out how to get the inline style=height value of the output below is my code so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://exampleonly.org/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
samples = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "example"})

for sample in samples:
    print(sample)
```

and my output is below

```
<div class="example" style="height: 50%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 20%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 40%;"></div>
```

Now what i want to get is the 50%,20% and 40% values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine class and attribute selectors to target elements, then extract the style attribute. Use re to extract the desired values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = '''
<div class="example" style="height: 50%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 20%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 40%;"></div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for i in soup.select('.example[style*=height]'):
    print(re.search(r'(\d+%)', i['style']).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="example" style="height: 50%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 20%;"></div>
<div class="example" style="height: 40%;"></div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
goal = [x['style'].split()[1][:-1] for x in soup.select('.example')]
print(goal)
```

Output:

```
['50%', '20%', '40%']
```